# How do I fix the encoding of the quotes?

Tags: html, wordpress, character-encoding

I am using the free plan of the wordpress.com platform to host reference information on a small site. The goal is to be able to copy the code from the site page and place it in your own IDE, such as VSCode. Since the plan is free, all Wordpress features have been cut to a minimum, including the installation of plugins. It is possible to use only standard blocks such as HTML, Code, Classic Editor, etc. When it became necessary to publish highlighted code, I did not find anything better than to copy it from my code editor and convert it to HTML, then insert it into Wordpress standard HTML block. And for the first time everything was fine, i.e. I was able to copy a block of highlighted code from a page on my site and paste it into the VSCode code editor. And the code was displayed in the same way as on the page. But suddenly, everything changed and the following problems arose: the single quotes character (') began to display as an opening single quote (‘) and a closing single quote (’), which makes the code inoperable and needs to be edited, which is extremely inconvenient:

```js
describe(‘Examples for Querying commands’, () => {
  before(‘Navigate to querying page’, () => {
    cy.visit(‘https://example.cypress.io/commands/querying‘);
  });
  // Скопируйте интересующий вас пример и вставьте его здесь
});
```

Double quotes began to display incorrectly on the site itself. Instead of ("), they began to display as (»):

```js
cy.get(‘[data-test-id=»test-example»]’)
```

What could such a metamorphosis be connected with? It happened after the next resave of the edited page. The single quote character is encoded on the page as &apos replacing it with the symbol (') itself does nothing either. You can watch it here: https://kitchensinkcypress.wordpress.com/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/. The site is under construction. Please tell me how I can overcome it?

Comment: @mplungjan that is the point I am asking about - somehow my valid quotes symbols are turned into invalid. I am using Google docs document to copy the code from and convert it into html on one of the online resources

Comment: No, the problem is Wordpress itself. For example: I have html snippet for one of the code examples located on the page. If I open this snippet separately in my browser it is displayed properly. But after being inserted into Wordpress html block it starts being displayed wrong (please, follow the link provided in my question)

Comment: So no problem, just try to understand what I am talking about :)

Comment: If I copy my code from VSCode directly to online converter I have the same result - the code snippet is displayed properly outside Wordpress but is corrupted after being inserted into Wordpress html module

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can treat this as an answer, but it would be an answer if this is Wordpress bug. I found out that the reason of the issue is page update. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create html snippet for the highlighted code example.
2. Save it into html file, open the file in browser and ensure that all characters are displayed properly.
3. Create HTML block on the page and insert there the content of the mentioned html file.
4. Open the page in browser and insure that the code is displayed properly.
5. Copy the code snippet from the page and paste it into VSCode editor. Ensure that the code is displayed properly.
6. Now make any changes anywhere on the web page except of the mentioned HTML block and press Save button.

**Expected result:** The mentioned code snippet is still displayed properly as no changes were maid inside its HTML block.

**Actual result:** The snippet has been corrupted. Double quotes (") is turned into (»), single quotes are displayed as opening single quote and closing single quotes if being copied from the page and pasted to VSCode editor:

```js
cy.get(‘[data-test-id=»test-example»]’)
```

which makes the code not usable. So I believe that this is a Wordpress bug as we have two different results for displaying of the same block of the html code without any user manipulation over this block.